# how does block damage work fundamentally in Robocraft?

Tags: robocraft

There are advanced armor design strategies called "Triforcing" - So in the interest of being able to design the perfect defense for different situations and understanding the trafeoffs between different strategies, I'd like to know how damage is fundamentally absorbed and spread by different block types.

This question is a combination:

- How does damage applied to a full block spread to blocks near by?
- How do the shapes of these near by blocks (or the block receiving thr hit) change the way damage is recieved or spread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Damage in Robocraft can spread only to adjacent blocks. When a powerful weapon, such as a railgun, destroys a block, the remaining weapon damage (the overkill) is applied to all of the blocks "touching" the destroyed block. The process repeats as long as there is any remaining damage. Note that you can tell if blocks are touching by building in the editor (the rules for building are the same as for damage spread).

If the red block is hit, damage will first spread to the orange blocks, and then the yellow blocks. Below this is shown with cubes.

[image: Cubes]

Below, with edges, you can see a white edge block directly above the red target. Although they are physically close, the are not considered to be touching. It can only take damage from shooting the red if the orange and yellow are destroyed first. Also note that the second layer is not going to receive damage as damage doesn't spread through empty space.

[image: Edges]

Corner blocks spread damage in even fewer directions.

[image: Corners]

Comment: Since this answer is old, does the game mechanics still work this way?